# Binding datagridview with data from LINQ query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, datagridview

I'd like to apologise in advance in case my question was answered before (also the problem is probably pretty basic too). I'm pretty new to programming and there's a good chance I fail to google for answers since I don't even have a grasp of what the problem really is.

I'm trying to bind datagridview with data from linq query to entities (using Entity Framework).

I'm using this code to achieve that:

```
DatabaseModelContainer context = new DatabaseModelContainer();
private void FormDocumentUpdateWT_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        context.DocumentDetailsSet.Load();
        this.documentDetailsBindingSource.DataSource = (from x in context.DocumentDetailsSet.Local
                                                        where x.DocumentHeaderId == currentDocument.Id
                                                        select new 
                                                        {

                                                          x.Inventory.Number,
                                                          x.Amount,
                                                          x.Containers.Name,
                                                          x.Separate,
                                                          x.Kanban

                                                        }).ToList();
        dataGridViewItems.DataSource = documentDetailsBindingSource;
        dataGridViewItems.Update();
        dataGridViewItems.Refresh();
}
```

Unfortunately this is not giving me any results (datagridview doesn't show anything), eventhough the query does return data.

When I change the code like below, datagridview actually updates but (obviously) I do not get the specific properties of my desire displayed.

```
 DatabaseModelContainer context = new DatabaseModelContainer();

 private void FormDocumentUpdateWT_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        context.DocumentDetailsSet.Load();
        this.documentDetailsBindingSource.DataSource = (from x in context.DocumentDetailsSet.Local
                                                        where x.DocumentHeaderId == currentDocument.Id
                                                        select new                                   {
                                                           x.Inventory, //this is changed
                                                           x.Amount,
                                                           x.Containers, // also changed
                                                           x.Separate,
                                                           x.Kanban

                                                        }).ToList();
        dataGridViewItems.DataSource = documentDetailsBindingSource;
        dataGridViewItems.Update();
        dataGridViewItems.Refresh();
    }
```

Can somebody explain to me how this works and how to work around this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe is because you're using an anonymous type in the `select` clause. Have you tried to use `select new Local {...}` instead of `select new {...}`?

Comment: If you're suggesting creating new class called Local then yes I tried it with no result unfortunately.